Appropiate distrution to model under-dispersed count data with missing zero class
I am working in the problem of finding the missing zero-class of data that comes from a counting event. My data is highly under-dispersed. In some cases:
$$ \bar{x}/s^2 >20, $$
with $\bar{x}$ and $s^2$ the sampling average and standard deviation.
I have tried to fit a generalized Poisson (GP) to my data:
$$ P(x) = \frac{\beta ( \beta + \alpha x)^{x-1} e^{-( \beta + \alpha x)}}{x!} .
$$
I followed this paper's expression of the first moments (eqs 6.1 and 6.2) of the (complete) GP:
$$ \alpha = 1 - \bigg( \frac{\bar{x}}{s^2} \bigg)^{1 / 2} \\ \beta = \bar{x} (1-\alpha)
$$
to infer the recursive expressions for the parameters of the zero-truncated (zt) GP:
$$    \beta_{i+1} = \bar{x} (1-\alpha_i)(1-e^{-\beta_i}) 
$$
$$ \alpha_{i+1} = 1 -\frac{\beta_{i+1}}{\bar{x}} 
$$
But I found this expressions are often unstable. An option is that the zt-GP is not suitable for such under-dispersed data.
Can you guys provide some insights on what is happening? Or perhaps suggest a more appropriate distribution (is possible my data could be over-dispersed sometimes).
